# Trouble with Input Validation and Play Again loop JAVA homework

Tags: java, loops, variable-assignment

my assignment for my CS1 class is to create a game similar to Rock, Paper, Scissors. The inputs are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. I need help figuring out how to prompt user to put in the correct inputs in case they input a number that's not 1-5. And I also need help inserting a "Play Again?" Loop. Please help I'm so stuck. I'm really struggling.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Moropinzee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String personPlay1;
        String personPlay2;
        String response;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        System.out.println("Hey, Let's Play Moropinzee!\n" + "Please enter a move.\n"
                + "Monkey = 1, Robot = 2, Pirate = 3, Ninja= 4, and Zombies = 5.");

        System.out.println("Player 1 plays: ");
        personPlay1 = scan.next();

        System.out.println("Player 2 plays ");
        personPlay2 = scan.next();

        if (personPlay1.equals(personPlay2))
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");

        else if (personPlay1.equals("1"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("2"))
                System.out.println("Monkey unplugs Robot. Player 1 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("2"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("1"))
                System.out.println("Monkey unplugs Robot. Player 2 win!!");

        if (personPlay1.equals("1"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("3"))
                System.out.println("Pirate skewers Monkey. Player 2 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("3"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("1"))
                System.out.println("Pirate skewers Monkey. Player 1 win!!");

        if (personPlay1.equals("1"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("4"))
                System.out.println("Monkey fools Ninja. Player 1 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("4"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("1"))
                System.out.println("Monkey fools Ninja. Player 2 win!!");

        if (personPlay1.equals("1"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("5"))
                System.out.println("Zombie savages Monkey. Player 2 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("5"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("1"))
                System.out.println("Zombie savages Monkey. Player 1 win!!");

        if (personPlay1.equals("2"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("3"))
                System.out.println("Pirate drowns Robot. Player 2 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("3"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("2"))
                System.out.println("Pirate drowns Robot. Player 1 win!!");

        if (personPlay1.equals("2"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("4"))
                System.out.println("Robot chokes Ninja. Player 1 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("4"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("2"))
                System.out.println("Robot chokes Ninja. Player 2 win!!");

        if (personPlay1.equals("2"))
            if (personPlay1.equals("5"))
                System.out.println("Robot crushes Zombie. Player 1 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("5"))
            if (personPlay1.equals("2"))
                System.out.println("Robot crushes Zombie. Player 2 win!!");

        if (personPlay1.equals("3"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("4"))
                System.out.println("Ninja karate chops Pirate. Player 2 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("4"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("3"))
                System.out.println("Ninja karate chops Pirate. Player 1 win!!");

        if (personPlay1.equals("3"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("5"))
                System.out.println("Zombie eats Pirate. Player 2 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("5"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("3"))
                System.out.println("Zombie eats Pirate. Player 1 win!!");

        if (personPlay1.equals("4"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("5"))
                System.out.println("Ninja decapitates Zombie. Player 1 win!!");
        if (personPlay1.equals("5"))
            if (personPlay2.equals("4"))
                System.out.println("Ninja decapitates Zombie. Player 2 win!!");

            else {

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the move? The word? The number? The whole equation, like `Monkey = 1`?

Comment: the number is the move. I just put monkey=1 and so on so that the player would know what number go with what character if that makes sense?

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering about the move being stored as a `String`, which should not be necessary if it is an `int`. See the answer below by @ScaryWombat, it will give you a lot of hints on how to resolve your task.

Comment: Looks like Tracy has run away.

Answer (score 0):

First of all consider creating an array for your messages

```
String [][] msgs = new String [6][6];
msgs[1][2] = "Monkey unplugs Robot. Player 1 win!!";
msgs[2][1] = "Monkey unplugs Robot. Player 2 win!!";
// etc

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
// get input
while (true) {
    System.out.println("enter number 1 or -1 to quit");
    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    if (num1 == -1) break;
    if (num1 < 1 || num1> 5) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println("enter number 2");
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    if (num2 < 1 || num2> 5) {
        continue;
    }

    System.out.println(msgs[num1][num2]);
}
```

Of course you need to add all the messages to the array and you maybe want to do further testing of invalid input, but at least this method prevent much much duplicated code

Answer (score 0):

The code provided by Scary Wombat is in most Ok, however you should use two while loops (instead of one) to avoid repeating of the program from the begining. And don't forgot to break both loops after they finished their tasks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Moropinzee {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Player1;
    int Player2;

    String [][] results = new String [6][6];
    results[1][2] = "Monkey unplugs Robot. Player 1 win!!";
    results[2][1] = "Monkey unplugs Robot. Player 2 win!!";
    results[1][3] = "Pirate skewers Monkey. Player 2 win!!";
    results[3][1] = "Pirate skewers Monkey. Player 1 win!!";
    results[1][4] = "Monkey fools Ninja. Player 1 win!!";
    results[4][1] = "Monkey fools Ninja. Player 2 win!!";
    results[1][5] = "Zombie savages Monkey. Player 2 win!!";
    results[5][1] = "Zombie savages Monkey. Player 1 win!!";
    results[2][3] = "Pirate drowns Robot. Player 2 win!!";
    results[3][2] = "Pirate drowns Robot. Player 1 win!!";
    results[2][4] = "Robot chokes Ninja. Player 1 win!!";
    results[4][2] = "Robot chokes Ninja. Player 2 win!!";
    results[2][5] = "Robot crushes Zombie. Player 1 win!!";
    results[5][2] = "Robot crushes Zombie. Player 2 win!!";
    results[3][4] = "Ninja karate chops Pirate. Player 2 win!!";
    results[4][3] = "Ninja karate chops Pirate. Player 1 win!!";
    results[3][5] = "Zombie eats Pirate. Player 2 win!!";
    results[5][3] = "Zombie eats Pirate. Player 1 win!!";
    results[4][5] = "Ninja decapitates Zombie. Player 1 win!!";
    results[5][4] = "Ninja decapitates Zombie. Player 2 win!!";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hey, Let's Play Moropinzee!\n" + "Please enter a move.\n"
            + "Monkey = 1, Robot = 2, Pirate = 3, Ninja= 4, and Zombies = 5.");



    while (true) {      
        System.out.println("Player 1 plays: ");
        Player1 = scan.nextInt();
        if (Player1 < 1 || Player1 > 5) {System.out.println("Please, enter a number in a range 1-5!!!");
                continue;}

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 plays ");
            Player2 = scan.nextInt();
            if (Player2 < 1 || Player2 > 5) {System.out.println("Please, enter a number in a range 1-5!!!");
                continue;}

            if (Player1==Player2) System.out.println("It's a tie!");
            else System.out.println(results[Player1][Player2]);
            System.out.println();
        break;
        } 

        System.out.println("Enter Yes (Y or y) if you'd like to continue, or any other letter to quit");
        String choise = scan.next();
        if (choise.equals("Y") || choise.equals("y")) continue;
        else System.out.println("The game is over.");
            break;
    }

}
}
```